# Como hacer que el valor dentro de una celda de una tabla HTML se convierta en variable

Tags: php, html5

Necesito que al clickear una celda el valor que hay dentro se convierta en variable para usarla mas adelante en una consulta en la base de datos, disculpen el codigo soy noob.
De antemano gracias

```
  <?php

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Conexión fallida: ".$conn->connect_error);
      }

    $salida = "";
    $prueba = "PRUEBA";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM sheet1 WHERE Legal NOT LIKE '' ORDER By AI LIMIT 25";

    if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
        $q = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM sheet1 WHERE AI LIKE '%$q%' OR DNI LIKE '%$q%' OR Nombre LIKE '%$q%' OR Apellido LIKE '%$q%' OR Namebirth LIKE '%$q%' OR Legal LIKE '$q' ";
    }
$resultado = $conn->query($query);
if ($resultado->num_rows>0) {
        $salida.="<head><link href='bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'></head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='bootstrap/css/estilor.css'><body><table border=1 class='tabla_datos'>
                <thead>
                    <tr id='titulo'>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>NOMBRE</th>
                        <th>SEGUNDO NOMBRE</th>
                        <th>APELLIDO</th>
                        <th>SEGUNDO APELLIDO</th>
                        <th>CÉDULA DE CIUDADANIA</th>
                        <th>Código</th>
                        <th>Area</th>
                        <th>Select</th>
                    </tr>

                </thead>


        <tbody>";

        while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            $codigo = $fila['Legal'];
            $salida.="<tr>
                        <td>".$fila['AI']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['Nombre']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['Namebirth']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['Apellido']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['Segundoapellido']."</td>
                        <td><a href='#resultado' data-toggle='modal'>".$fila['DNI']."</a></td>
                        <td>".$fila['Legal']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['Categoria']."</td>
                        <td><input type='radio'></td>
                    </tr>";

        }
        $salida.="</tbody></table></div>
            <script src='bootstrap/js/jquery.js'></script>
            <script src='bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
            <script src='bootstrap/js/script.js'></script></body>";
    }else{
        $salida.="NO HAY DATOS :( 
            <img src=''>";
    }


    echo $salida;

    $conn->close();
  ?>
```

Necesito que al darle clik a DNI me haga una consulta con ese numero de cedula

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero que se me ocurre es que le des un atributo arbitrario a tus celdas para que puedas reconocer que 
 variable es la que va a almacenar, segundo escuchar el evento onclick de esas en particular y cuando ocurra,
 hacer lo que desees con esa variable y el valor, este seria tu html:

```
  "<tr>
        <td data-col='AI'>".$fila['AI']."</td>
        <td data-col='Nombre'>".$fila['Nombre']."</td>
        <td data-col='Namebirth'>".$fila['Namebirth']."</td>
        <td data-col='Apellido'>".$fila['Apellido']."</td>
        <td data-col='Segundoapellido'>".$fila['Segundoapellido']."</td>
        <td data-col='DNI'><a href='#resultado' data-toggle='modal'>".$fila['DNI']."</a></td>
        <td data-col='Legal'>".$fila['Legal']."</td>
        <td data-col='Categoria'>".$fila['Categoria']."</td>
        <td><input type='radio'></td>
  </tr>";
```

El javascript seria algo como:

```
  var celdas = document.querySelectorAll('td[data-col]');
  celdas.forEach(function(celda){
        celda.addEventListener('click', function(event){
              console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data-col') + '=' + event.target.innerText);
              // Esto puedes reemplazarlo por un ajax solo debes saber que
              // event.target.getAttribute('data-col') seria el nombre de tu variable y 
              // event.target.innerText seria tu valor
        })
  })
```

Comment: Gracias Dariel,
Me podrías hacer un ejemplo de como mostrarías el valor de la variable seleccionada en un echo?